SRID in PostGIS -> ST_SRID !== Find_SRID
i am trying to understand why I get two different values for
those two Querys (to a PostGIS db)
SELECT ST_SRID(ground_geometry) FROM cjdb.city_object LIMIT 1;

select Find_SRID('cjdb', 'city_object', 'ground_geometry')

How can the row be 0 when the geometry is 3857?

Find_SRID:"Returns the integer SRID of the specified geometry column by searching through the GEOMETRY_COLUMNS table." Do you have your table properly registered into geometry_columns?

Excursion:
PostGIS (custom) data types utilize the PostgreSQL type mod[ification] system that allows for flexible, system-accessible meta data storage alongside the actual values; for both data types GEOMETRY & GEOGRAPHY you can explicitly set both the geometry type and SRID, e.g. GEOMETRY(POINT, 4326).
Thus the SRID is potentially stored in two locations:

in the GEOMETRY|GEOGRAPHY row value types - per row
in the GEOMETRY|GEOGRAPHY column data type definition - per column

where the column data type definition has precedence over the value types, i.e. you are not allowed to pass in value types that have type mods that are not supported by the column data type!
In addition to that, PostGIS implements bookkeeping of its actionable relations (tables using its types) through the geometry_columns|geography_columns Views - which assemble information about tables and columns using the PostGIS types from the PostgreSQL core tables.

While there is more to all that above, the important part here is that you can have an SRID set at the row value level while the column data type is set to be generic (which actually defaults to SRID = 0!):
CREATE TABLE srid_test (
  id   INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  geom GEOMETRY  -- column data type definition; generic, but will be set to 0
);

INSERT INTO srid_test
  VALUES
    -- we explicitly set the SRID at the row value type level here
    ( ST_SetSRID('POINT(0 0)'::GEOMETRY, 4326) )
;

The row value function ST_SRID reads out the encoded meta info from each value type:
SELECT
  ST_SRID(geom)
FROM
  srid_test
;

 st_srid 
---------
    4326
(1 row)

while the column type function Find_SRID parses the geometry_columns|geography_columns Views for the column data type definition:
SELECT
  srid
FROM
  public.geometry_columns
WHERE
  geometry_columns.f_table_name = 'srid_test'
;

 srid 
------
    0
(1 row)

This is almost exactly what Find_SRID runs internally.

Solution:
Since PostGIS introduced support for the PostgreSQL type mod system it is unnecessary to explicitly register geometry columns in the system - except for Views! - so I assume you haven't set your column data type mods correctly. You can run an ALTER COLUMN command to change the column type accordingly:
ALTER TABLE srid_test
  ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE GEOMETRY(POINT, 4326)
;

which then results in the correct SRID in the system:
SELECT
  srid
FROM
  public.geometry_columns
WHERE
  geometry_columns.f_table_name = 'srid_test'
;

 srid 
------
 4326
(1 row)

Of note is that you cannot just set the SRID type mod, you will also have to define the geometry type - POINT in the above example, but you can also set it to be generic, i.e. GEOMETRY(GEOMETRY, 4326).
Make sure you properly adapt my example to your data setup, e.g. using SRID = 3857. Note that this will fail if any of the row value types have a different SRID than the column data type - use ST_Transform to solve that:
ALTER TABLE srid_test
  ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE GEOMETRY(POINT, 3857)
    USING ST_Transform(geom, 3857)
;

